# How to generate same SHA1 for updated apk?

Tags: android, google-play

After my hard disk crash, I've lost all my data including the keystore file. Though I remember all the information I have inserted to generate the keystore file. Now without the keystore, I can't update my app in google play store :(

Google play is showing me this error now:

[...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zklut.png)

Is there any way to generate the JKS file so that it lets me upload the APK in the Google play?

Answer (score 1):

> After my hard disk crash, I've lost all my data including the keystore file

Restore it from the backup that you made of your hard drive. If you are not backing up your computers, stop using those computers until you start backing them up.

> Is there any way to generate the JKS file so that it lets me upload the APK in the Google play?

No.